# Issue with numerical minimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Using `Nminimize` and simulated annealing, I have been trying to numerically minimize the function:

$\qquad f(\theta,\,\phi) = {\mathsf{Abs}[\mathsf{Cos}\,{\theta/2}]^4 + e^{-2 \mathsf{Re}[I \phi]} \mathsf{Abs}[\mathsf{Cos}\,{\theta/2}]^2 \mathsf{Abs}[\mathsf{Sin}\,{\theta/2]}^2}$

where, $(0\le\theta\le\pi)$, $(0\le\phi\le2\pi)$.

Although the function returns a real value (I also declared $\theta$, $\phi$ as real), *Mathematica* produces the message

> objective function should be scalar valued.

It would be very  helpful if someone can point out what went wrong here.

Comment: Please, post the code you are using.

Comment: Isn't $Re[I \phi]=0$ if $\phi$ is real...? Or is $I$ not the imaginary unit.

Comment: $NMinimize[f({\theta},{\phi}),{0<= \theta <= \pi},{0<=\phi<= 2\pi},{\theta,\phi}]$. yes, "I" is imaginary.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful.  You can edit your question to update it with the code.

Comment: Isn't the minimum obviously `0`? (Consider `Cos[t/2] == 0` & `f[...] >=0 `.)

Comment: `NMinimize[]` works for me. But my code is based on your partial code.  Try restarting the kernel and re-executing your code. If that doesn't work, post your complete code so that we can copy it directly into *M* and test it.

Comment: yes, the minimized result is 0 for what I posted. I wanted to test it out using Mathematica before stepping on a bigger problem.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your useful suggestions , I will post the code here  in few hours

Comment: `NMinimize[{{{Abs[0.25 E^(4 Im[\[Phi]]) Abs[Sin[\[Theta]/2]]^4+Abs[Cos[\[Theta]/2]]^2 (Abs[Cos[\[Theta]/2]]^2+0.74 E^(2 Im[\[Phi]]) Abs[Sin[\[Theta]/2]]^2)-0.86 Cos[\[Theta]/2] Cos[Conjugate[\[Theta]]/2] Sin[\[Theta]/2] Sin[Conjugate[\[Theta]]/2]]}},{0<=\[Theta]<=\[Pi]},{0<=\[Phi]<=2 \[Pi]}},{\[Theta],\[Phi]},Method->SimulatedAnnealing]`

Comment: I have copy pasted the code in plain text form. You can easily copy paste this into Mathematica and test. Please let me know if anything more is required with respect to the code format.

Comment: The code that I posted as comment  is an extension to the original problem that i posted